# Checking valid date format in oracle

Tags: oracle

In source table we are having 4 date field columns. 2 columns are having DATE as their datatype and other are varchar2. What I want to check is the incoming data for date fields are valid, if not it should be rejected if we found it is having invalid format (other than dd/mm/yyyy) and if it like 32/02/1999 or 34/15/1999 etc.

Can you please give me a sql query to check it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
 in_txt  VARCHAR2; -- to be converted
 in_fmt_txt VARCHAR2 := 'DD-MON-YYYY';     -- optional format
BEGIN
     -- Try to convert in_txt to a DATE.  If it works, fine.
     RETURN     TO_DATE (in_txt, in_fmt_txt);
EXCEPTION     -- If TO_DATE caused an error, then this is not a valid DATE: return NULL
     WHEN OTHERS
     THEN
          RETURN NULL;
END ;
```